# Adding text over ImageView in Android

Tags: android, textview

```
public void addNewImageToScreen (int resourceId)
{
    if (mLastNewCell != null) mLastNewCell.setVisibility (View.GONE);

    FrameLayout imageHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById (R.id.image_source_frame);
    if (imageHolder != null) {
       FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                                                   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                                                   Gravity.CENTER);
       ImageCell newView = new ImageCell (this);
       newView.setImageResource (resourceId);
       imageHolder.addView (newView, lp);
       newView.mEmpty = false;
       newView.mCellNumber = -1;
       mLastNewCell = newView;
       mImageCount++;

       // Have this activity listen to touch and click events for the view.
       newView.setOnClickListener(this);
       newView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
       newView.setOnTouchListener (this);

    }
}
```

I have used the above code to dynamically generate image on screen. now i want to add some text over the image cell. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why you cant add an ImageView and A TextView in a relativeLayout then add that RelativeLayout inside your frameLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageCell is a class thats Implements ImageView so using a FrameLayout i could overlap text on it 
Thanks @Triode